# Nagios alert based on scheduled MySQL queries results

Tags: mysql, nagios, linux-networking

I have installed Nagios 4.0 on my Ubuntu 14.0 and i want a plugin to alert me based on daily scheduled MySql queries ..

if the result of `( select count(*) from tableName > 10 )`  raise a critical alert or `< 10` warning alert this query run every day for example.

is it even possible ?! if so can you tell any suggested plugins , ideas or where to start ..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do exactly that.  The test is pretty trivial, inasmuch as it connects to a custom database called `nagios` and selects from a table that contains just a single numeric value, alerting if that value isn't `74581` - but I figure if `mysql` works well enough to retrieve that exact number from a table, it's probably fine.  You could run more complex queries, though.

```
command[check_mysql]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_mysql_query -H 127.0.0.1 -d nagios -u user -p pass -q "select * from nagioscheck;" -c 74581:74581 -w 74581:74581
```

This is invoked by NRPE (hence the format of the above, which is from `nrpe.cfg`); the `check_mysql_query` plugin is a standard nagios plugin, at least in my distro (CentOS 6 with the `nagios-plugins` package from RPMForge).  It can also be found [here](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Databases/check_mysql_query-2Epl-%28Advanced-Nagios-Plugins-Collection%29/details) (with thanks to the OP for the link).

Comment: +1 for check_mysql_query plugIn [link](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Databases/check_mysql_query-2Epl-%28Advanced-Nagios-Plugins-Collection%29/details)

Answer (score 0):

Needed to delete the character `;` at the end of the query to get it to work. Didn't understand why, but "`select * from nagioscheck;`" returned an error and "`select * from nagioscheck`" works.

Comment: The semicolon (`;`) terminates the query **interactively** but it isn't part of the query itself.  When sending SQL statements from code you should usually leave it off.